# Why can't cosets in the polynomial ring $\Bbb Z[x]$ be written as a polynomial of lesser degree?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am having a hard time understanding the reason that we cannot express cosets of the polynomial ring $\Bbb Z[x]$ with lower degree.

For example, I am given a function ${f(x) = 4x^3+2}$ in ${\mathbb Z[x]}$ and am asked why it is that I cannot express the cosets ${\mathbb Z[x]/(4x^3+2)}$    as    $${a + bx +cx^2 + (f(x))}$$

Usually when working with field coefficients of polynomials, such as ${\mathbb R}$ or ${\mathbb Q}$ I'd have the "condition" that ${x^3 = -1/2}$. But why can I not have the condition that ${4x^3 = -2}$ since those are still in ${\mathbb Z}$?

My professor has alluded to the fact that we cannot have cosets in ${\mathbb Z[x]}$ of this form, but he didn't elaborate as to why, and the provided text doesn't have anything about this topic that I can find.

Comment: The simplest thing not of that form is $x^3 +(f)$ - can you show that can't be written that way?

Answer (score 1):

This is because long division of polynomials only works when the leading coefficient of $f$ is a unit.

Let me elaborate a bit. Consider any nonzero polynomial $f\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$. For two polynomials $P,R\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$, we have  $P+(f)=R+(f)\iff P=R+Qf$ for some $Q\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

Now assume further that given $P$, there exists an $R$ such that $\deg(R)<\deg(f)$ and $P+(f)=R+(f),$ so we would have $P=Qf+R$ with $\deg(R)<\deg(f)$. Viewing this equality in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, by uniqueness of quotient and remainder in Euclidean division of polynomials, $Q$ and $R$ are necessarily respectively the quotient and remainder of the long division of $P$ by $f$.

However, if the leading coefficient of $f$ is not $\pm 1 $ (which are the only units of $\mathbb{Z}$), it may happen that these $Q$ and $R$ do not belong to $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

In this case, $R$ will not exist.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, this makes sense to me. Just to be clear, though, this is because division isn't necessarily defined for the coefficients which lie in Z correct? So we can't just simply divide because then the coefficients could be fractional which obviously aren't integers?

Comment: exactly. You can only guarantee a quotient and remainder with integral coefficients only if you divide by a polynomial whose leading coefficient is $\pm 1$.